# Pulling components out of a Features module into a Drupal site

Tags: 7, features

I have a site that has some functionality provided by a Features module. They include a view, some nodes, and some content types. Now, we don't want them in the Feature anymore; we want them as native Drupal things.

How do we migrate components provided by a Feature module back into Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Feature Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) module. The main goal of the module is to give the ability to remove elements from a feature and put them back to the DB.
It adds a "Safe Create Feature" button to the recreate feature form, that detects the element that has been removed from the feature and saves them in an unlink file.
In order to save the elements to the DB you need to go to the admin/build/features/unlink page, check the element you need to import and submit.